# Problem in using viewModelScope with LiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I am using `viewModelScope` in the `ViewModel` which calls a suspend function in the repository as shown below:

**ViewModel**

```
class DeepFilterViewModel(val repo: DeepFilterRepository) : ViewModel() {

var deepFilterLiveData: LiveData<Result>? = null

 fun onImageCompressed(compressedImage: File): LiveData<Result>? {
    if (deepFilterLiveData == null) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            deepFilterLiveData =  repo.applyFilter(compressedImage)
        }

    }
    return deepFilterLiveData
 }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class DeepFilterRepository {

suspend fun applyFilter(compressedImage: File): LiveData<Result> {
    val mutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result>()
    mutableLiveData.value = Result.Loading

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        mutableLiveData.value = Result.Success("Done")

    }
    return mutableLiveData
 }
}
```

I am observing the LiveData from the Fragment as shown below:

```
 viewModel.onImageCompressed(compressedImage)?.observe(this, Observer { result ->
        when (result) {

            is Result.Loading -> {
                loader.makeVisible()
            }

            is Result.Success<*> -> {
                // Process result

            }
        }
    })
```

The problem is I am getting no value from the LiveData. If I don't use `viewModelScope.launch {}` as shown below, then everything works fine.

```
class DeepFilterViewModel(val repo: DeepFilterRepository) : ViewModel() {

var deepFilterLiveData: LiveData<Result>? = null

 fun onImageCompressed(compressedImage: File): LiveData<Result>? {
    if (deepFilterLiveData == null) {
            deepFilterLiveData =  repo.applyFilter(compressedImage)
    }
    return deepFilterLiveData
 }
}
```

I don't know what I am missing. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
   deepFilterLiveData =  repo.applyFilter(compressedImage)
}
```

returns immediately so when you first invoke the `onImageCompressed()` method you return `null` as `deepFilterLiveData`. Because in your UI you use `?.` on the `null` return value of `onImageCompressed()` the `when` clause will not be reached. The code without the coroutine works because in that case you have sequential code, your ViewModel awaits for the repository call.

To solve this you could keep the LiveData for the ViewModel-UI interaction and return the values directly from the repository method:

```
class DeepFilterRepository {

    suspend fun applyFilter(compressedImage: File) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Result.Success("Done")
    }

}
```

And the ViewModel:

```
class DeepFilterViewModel(val repo: DeepFilterRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _backingLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result>()
    val deepFilterLiveData: LiveData<Result>
       get() = _backingLiveData

    fun onImageCompressed(compressedImage: File) {
        // you could also set Loading as the initial state for _backingLiveData.value           
       _backingLiveData.value = Result.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _backingLiveData.value = repo.applyFilter(compressedImage)
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: How to observe this in a Fragment?